# Recent change in pronouncing homage

Tags: pronunciation

I’ve noticed that homage is now often pronounced hom-aag with a French accent not hom-ige as previously used. Anyone else noticed this?

Comment: That's the original pronunciation. The word comes from French. Around 1300. So people have been noticing this for 700 years now.

Comment: Similarly the I hear **garage** pronounced both ways.

Comment: I had believed ever since my schooldays 50+ years ago that the English word 'homage' was pronounced with a silent 'h'; it's only in the past few years that I discovered that it's usual to sound the 'h'. (However, it _is_ pronounced in the French way when it means a tribute to a writer, film director etc.)

Answer (score 6):

The pronunciation most dictionaries list as most common is *HOM-ij*, with stress on the first syllable and with a sounded *h*. However, *OM-ij* and *oh-MAHZH* with silent *h* are becoming increasingly common.

Looking at the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+homage%2Can+homage&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20homage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20homage%3B%2Cc0), it looks as though the pronunciation flipped around 1800 from silent *h* to what is now considered the traditional pronunciation.

[image: Frequencies of "a homage" and "an homage" in Google Books]

But that also coincides with the approximate time English pronunciation began to be standardized—namely the advent of John Walker's *A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary* (1791) and Thomas Sheridan's *A General Dictionary of the English Language* (1780)—so it might be indicative of a prescriptive standardization rather than an actual immediate change in people's pronunciation.

From a [2010 *New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/07/magazine/07FOB-onlanguage-t.html) by Ben Zimmer:

> While most U.S. dictionaries list *HOM-ij* first, one exception is Merriam-Webster’s Collegiate Dictionary. Joshua S. Guenter, Merriam-Webster’s pronunciation editor, explained to me that prior to the Tenth Edition of the dictionary in 1993, the pronunciation of homage was given with the initial “h” in parentheses, “indicating the two variants were about equally common.” Starting with the Tenth, they began giving a slight edge to *OM-ij*. “Our citation files do show the ‘h’-less variant to be more common than the ‘h’-ful one, though not by a huge degree,” Guenter said.

French /h/ had already disappeared by the time of the Norman Conquest, so /h/ in *homage* is indeed an English innovation, whether it was reintroduced only once or many times (probably the latter). Zimmer says:

> As with many other imports from Norman French into Middle English, the initial “h” was not originally pronounced in *homage*. Eventually, so-called spelling pronunciation introduced the “h” sound to words like *habit, host, hospital* and *human*. Some words resisted the extra puff of aspiration, like *heir, honest, honor* and *hour* ... Starting around the eighteenth century, *homage* joined the “h”-ful crowd.

The pronunciation more faithful to French, *oh-MAHZH*, is apparently much more recent as [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homage) seems to be the only dictionary that has caught up on it. It is generally confined to the relatively new sense of an artistic tribute, so, Zimmer argues, it may be understood as a reintroduction of French *hommage*, comparable to the way [*auteur*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/auteur) is now re-borrowed into English, which refers to a filmmaker with a distinct style like Scorsese or Wes Anderson, not just any "author".

Zimmer concludes:

> Listening to 10 recent uses of the word *homage* by on-the-air personalities [on NPR], I found an even split: five for *oh-MAZH* and five for *OM-ij*, with the latter generally reserved for the “respect” meaning, as in *pay homage*. The *HOM-ij* pronunciation, meanwhile, seems to be losing out to its trendier h-less rivals, despite the protestations of traditionalists. And since it’s a fight of two against one, “a homage” may, over time, become increasingly rare.

Comment: That’s why [the OED says](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87853?rskey=jZzcZb&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid): “Sense 3b may partly show a reborrowing of French *hommage*, which shows similar extended or metaphorical uses in the arts. A perception of such reborrowing is reflected by the pronunciation Brit. /ɒˈmɑːʒ/,  U.S. /ˌoʊˈmɑʒ/.” As a recommendation, I would edit your post to include the actual pronunciations using standard IPA notation. The other two are Brit. /ˈhɒmɪdʒ/,  U.S. /ˈ(h)ɑmɪdʒ/  respectively.

Comment: +1. Nice use of Ngram to show evidence of probable long-term changes in pronunciation preference.